# Javascript function with code as input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript function:

```
<script>
function clicker(text){
    var thediv=document.getElementById('displaybox');
    if(thediv.style.display == "none"){
        thediv.style.display = "";
        thediv.innerHTML = "<table width='100%' height='100%'><tr><td align='center' valign='middle' width='100%' height='100%'><img src='Images/Voorstellen/IMG_7355.JPG' width='auto%' height='400px'><br><br><p class='p5'>My name is blablablabla</p><br><a href='#' onclick='return clicker();'>CLOSE WINDOW</a></td></tr></table>";
    }else{
        thediv.style.display = "none";
        thediv.innerHTML = '';
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

No I want the location of the image + the text as input (in thediv.innerhtml = ...). But the text contains html code, for instant 
. How can I make the function so that I can have the image link as input variabel and the text as a second variabele but in html code?

Comment: You not not have a Java function.

Comment: Note: Java and Javascript are two different languages. This is javascript.

Comment: I will not buy this record, it is scratched.

Comment: My hovercraft is full of eels.

Comment: Did someone call my name?

Comment: I was hoping you'd show up.

Comment: :) damn phrase book strikes again!

Comment: Why do you want them in html code? Can you just concatenate them inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert variables into strings, you must compose it like this, quotes ending and plus signs indicating concatenation:

```
var name = "lawm";    
var stringAndVar = "My name is " + name + "!";
```

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition)

So therefore, your solution is:

```
thediv.innerHTML = "<table width='100%' height='100%'><tr><td align='center' valign='middle' width='100%' height='100%'><img src='" + input_variabel + "' width='auto%' height='400px'><br><br><p class='p5'>" + second_variabele + "</p><br><a href='#' onclick='return clicker();'>CLOSE WINDOW</a></td></tr></table>";
```

I strongly suggest you take the javascript course at [codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com/), it will help you out greatly with things like this.

Comment: Okay thanks, I only need it to build a site for a group project. For this reason I use code which I find online (for instance javascript) and use it for the site (though I don't understand it completely). I now introduced your suggestion but now my function does not run at all. Nothing happens when I click on the link. Any idea?